# How To Correctly Determine The Version Number?

Tags: version-control, versioning

I'm now updating a lot of my products for Android. The problem is that I don't know exactly how to choose the correct version number. At the time I'm doing like this, where `x` is the part of the version:

- `x.` - Great improvements
- `.x` - Number of bug fixes and minor improvements
- `.y.x` - Number minor changes

So I want to know if this is the correct way to make this and if isn't how should I make

Comment: In general: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/121795/what-version-numbering-scheme-do-you-recommend. In details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3377655/code-version-change-rules/3377717#3377717

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only really well determined answer is that new version number should be greater than old version number by some ordering.  The usual one is numeric, (0.1, 0.1.1, 0.1.2... 0.1.9, 0.2) but some people end up with a lexicographic sort of order, like 0.1, 0.2 ... 0.11... 0.22 ... 0.981 and so on.  Your scheme sounds perfectly plausible; it depends on how you measure "major improvement" and "minor change."

A lot of people use a top-level change to indicate "I'm going to charge you to upgrade."