# How can I know a version is the most stable version from version number?

Tags: netbeans, version-control, project-management, project

For example, netbeans has versions like 6.9.1; 7.0.0; 7.1.1 etc. Does the second number in the hierarchy mean improvement and the first is more about introducing new functionality, which makes it more likely to have bugs. So how do I interpret these version numbers, especially if I am willing to get the most stable version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the general case, version numbers have no fixed semantics.  A common convention is to use a "major" version number to signify major changes, and "minor" version numbers to signify small changes, but this is not cast in stone.  The recent [release of Linux 3.0](http://www.engadget.com/2011/05/30/linus-torvalds-releases-linux-kernel-version-3-to-celebrate-20-y/) is a good illustration -- the major version number was incremented purely for PR value; the release was no more significant than earlier releases in the 2.xx series.

Some projects have a stable / unstable convention; odd-numbered minor version numbers are development versions, and the even-numbered minor versions are release versions.  The Linux project uses this convention, as do Gnome and various other open source projects.

TeX has a playful version numbering convention of its own; it goes from 3.14, to 3.141, to 3.1415, to 3.14159 etc. (Hint: pi.)

See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_versioning

Answer (score 1):

Each product has to describe its own version number policy.

For instance, Netbeans allude to it in its [Guidelines](http://netbeans.org/community/guidelines/process.html)

Usually:

- the third number means: "bug fix only, no API evolution", and you can see it when checking API changes [for 7.1.1](http://bits.netbeans.org/7.1.1/javadoc/apichanges.html), or [for 7.1.2](http://bits.netbeans.org/7.1.2/javadoc/apichanges.html)
- the second number means "API changes, but still backward compatible": see [7.1 release](http://bits.netbeans.org/7.1/javadoc/apichanges.html)
- the first number is for "API changes, possibly not compatible with the previous versions": [see 7.0 release](http://bits.netbeans.org/7.0/javadoc/apichanges.html).
  You can have deprecated API fully removed, existing API modified, ...
  A migration guide is involved.

Lots of other versioning policies exist out there.
See:

- "[Code version change “rules”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3377655/code-version-change-rules/3377717#3377717)")
- "[What version numbering scheme do you recommend?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121795/what-version-numbering-scheme-do-you-recommend)"

The official document on such policies is in **[semver.org: Semantic versioning](http://semver.org/)**.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the [Label](http://version-control.net/version-control-howto/2-6-label-command/) feature? You can add comments to this specific version and it's easy for you to find and get it in the future.

Comment: irrelevant.. your answer is about SEO